# SAS: How to group the multi column data into single column?

Tags: csv, sas

I have obtained the following result from a data and it looks like below:

[image: Obtained]

but i want to subset the data according to the image given below:

[image: Want]

Any easiest way to carry out the same. Moreover i want to find out the percentage of exposure of each Variable. That is for 'A' the percentage exposure will be 331/(331+941+820+444+658) and similarly for each 'Levels' the percentage has to be found. Can anyone tell me the correct method to do this.

The code to find out the Table1 is as follows with the data:

Data:

```
Policy_Number,var1,var2,var3,Exposure
1,B,H,J,191
2,B,F,Unknown,174
3,C,Unknown,I,153
4,B,G,L,192
5,Unknown,E,Unknown,184
6,D,E,K,113
7,C,Unknown,I,140
8,A,H,I,133
9,C,F,I,194
10,Unknown,G,Unknown,105
11,B,H,L,172
12,A,Unknown,I,198
13,D,E,K,155
14,Unknown,G,K,177
15,B,H,Unknown,100
16,D,Unknown,J,176
17,B,E,I,112
18,Unknown,E,J,192
19,C,Unknown,K,146
20,C,G,Unknown,187
```

Code:

```
    data try2;
infile 'complex.csv' dsd dlm = ',' FIRSTOBS = 2;
Length Policy_Number Var1 $ 10 Var2 $ 10 Var3 $ 10 Exposure 3;
input Policy_Number $ Var1 $ Var2 $ Var3 $ Exposure;
run;

/*When the variables are known*/
proc summary data=try2;
   class Var1 Var2 Var3;
   ways 1;
   freq Exposure;
   output out=test(rename=(_freq_=TotExposures));
   run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from your csv file, you can get the same output via `proc freq` + 1 data step, rather than `proc summary` + `data step` + `proc sql`:

```
data mycsv;
    infile cards dsd dlm=',';
    Length Policy_Number Var1 $ 10 Var2 $ 10 Var3 $ 10 Exposure 3;
    input Policy_Number $ Var1 $ Var2 $ Var3 $ Exposure;
    cards;
1,B,H,J,191
2,B,F,Unknown,174
3,C,Unknown,I,153
4,B,G,L,192
5,Unknown,E,Unknown,184
6,D,E,K,113
7,C,Unknown,I,140
8,A,H,I,133
9,C,F,I,194
10,Unknown,G,Unknown,105
11,B,H,L,172
12,A,Unknown,I,198
13,D,E,K,155
14,Unknown,G,K,177
15,B,H,Unknown,100
16,D,Unknown,J,176
17,B,E,I,112
18,Unknown,E,J,192
19,C,Unknown,K,146
20,C,G,Unknown,187
;
run;

/*Optional - prevent output being displayed in the results area*/
ods _all_ close;

/*Divert proc freq output to a sas dataset test1*/
ods output onewayfreqs = test1(keep = var1-var3 frequency percent);

/*Produce weighted frequency tables*/
proc freq data = mycsv;
    weight exposure;
    table var1-var3;
run;

/*Turn listing output back on again so that subsequent code works as normal*/
ods listing; 

/*Tidy up*/
data want;
    length varname $32 varlevel $8;
    array myvars $ var1-var3;
    set test1;
    varlevel = coalescec(of myvars[*]);
    do i = 1 to dim(myvars);
        if not(missing(myvars[i])) then varname = vname(myvars[i]);
    end;
    drop var1-var3 i;
run;
```

If all your variables are of the same type (character / numeric) and they are all adjacent to one another in the column order of your dataset, you can use a double-dash list to define the array without having to rename them sequentially. e.g. instead of `var1-var3` you can type
`firstNumericVar--lastNumericVar`. You can create a view of your original dataset with the appropriate column order if necessary.

### Explanation

By default, proc freq writes output to the results area, which includes the number and percentage of observations with each level of each variable in the requested frequency table. This is already pretty close to what you're trying to do, and `proc summary` doesn't have any direct equivalent option.

The first tweak is to specify `weight exposure;` so that we're adding up values of exposure rather than counting rows within each level. Now the figures are correct, and we just need to get some sort of output dataset...

By default, `proc freq` doesn't produce an output sas dataset, and so the 'usual' way of getting it to do this is to specify `/out=mytable` on the `tables` statement. However, if you try something like this:

```
proc freq data = mycsv;
    table var1-var3 /out = mytable;
run;
```

, `mytable` will only include the frequencies for the last variable in the list, in this case var3. So we have two options - write out one `table` statement per variable with different `/out=` datasets and append them all together (really messy), or use `ods output`.

The trick here is to know that you can set `ods trace on;` before running any proc, and then when you check the log, SAS will tell you the internal names it uses for all the tables it prints to the results area. In this case, the output looks like this:

```
 57         ods trace on;
 58         proc freq data = mycsv;
 59         weight exposure;
 60         table var1-var3;
 61         run;


 Output Added:
 -------------
 Name:       OneWayFreqs
 Label:      One-Way Frequencies
 Template:   Base.Freq.OneWayFreqs
 Path:       Freq.Table1.OneWayFreqs
 -------------

 Output Added:
 -------------
 Name:       OneWayFreqs
 Label:      One-Way Frequencies
 Template:   Base.Freq.OneWayFreqs
 Path:       Freq.Table2.OneWayFreqs
 -------------

 Output Added:
 -------------
 Name:       OneWayFreqs
 Label:      One-Way Frequencies
 Template:   Base.Freq.OneWayFreqs
 Path:       Freq.Table3.OneWayFreqs
 -------------
 NOTE: There were 20 observations read from the data set WORK.MYCSV.
 NOTE: PROCEDURE FREQ used (Total process time):
       real time           0.05 seconds
       cpu time            0.06 seconds
```

The interesting bit is the table name `OneWayFreqs`, which appears 3 times, corresponding to the 3 1-way frequency tables plotted in the results area for var1-var3. Now that we know this table name, we can tell sas to send the same output to a SAS dataset of our choice when we next run the proc, which is what this statement is doing:

```
ods output onewayfreqs = test1(keep = var1-var3 frequency percent);
```

It just so happens that when multiple instances of the same table are produced, they are all output to the destination data set, not just the last one. I didn't actually know it worked that way until I tried this just now!

One other point worth mentioning - normally, you might set `noprint` on your `proc freq` statement if you didn't want to produce a really big table in the results area when using something like
 `table var1 / out = mytable;` with a large dataset with lots of levels. However, that would also prevent anything from being sent to ODS, preventing any datasets specified via `ods output` from being created. So instead, you have to tell ODS itself not to produce any other output via `ods _all_ close` or `ods select none`.

Comment: appreciated :) an answer that i can expect. can you explain the code as well? i am keen to know the logic behind this?

Comment: Both of us given a very similar answers so array is the way to solve it.

Comment: @desmond.carros - explanation added

Comment: @user667489 The more modern way to suppress output from a PROC is to use ODS SELECT NONE;  This way you don't have to know anything about the output destinations.   ODS \_ALL\_ CLOSE is a heavy hammer.  Also you toss out the gift that PROC FREQ provides in ONEWAYFREQS the variables F_: and TABLE.

Comment: @data_null_ - is that new syntax as of a fairly recent version of SAS?

Comment: @user667489 I only have access to documentation back to 9.2 and it is there.  I think it has always been there but most of the examples of ODS this or that have mostly use ODS CLOSE.  I only become fully aware of the virtues of ODS SELECT in the last couple of years myself.  Much easier that having to worry about active destinations.

Comment: @user667489 i understood the explanation you added. and the code is exceptionally understandable.

Answer (score 1):

The data step deals with joining all non missing var-var3 into one by using an array. I loop through the array and once I find a non-empty element, I output the non-missing element and its name by using vname array function. It is important that there is one and only one non-missing value, just like in your data.

the proc SQL summurises by grouping exposure, then it merges back summary statistics to work out percentage proportion.

I hope it makes sense.

See my code below:

```
data want (drop=i var1-var3);
    set test;
    array var_array[*] var:;
    do i=1 to dim(var_array);
        if var_array[i] ne "" then
            do;
                levels = var_array[i];
                variable = vname(var_array[i]);
                output;
            end;
    end;
run;


PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_FOR_WANT AS 
   SELECT t1._TYPE_, 
          t1.levels, 
          t1.variable, 
          /* SUM_of_TotExposures */
            (SUM(t1.TotExposures)) AS SUM_of_TotExposures, 
          t1.TotExposures, 
          /* Calculation */
            (t1.TotExposures / (SUM(t1.TotExposures))) FORMAT=PERCENTN6. AS Calculation
      FROM WORK.WANT t1
      GROUP BY t1.variable;
QUIT;
```

Comment: is there any other way beside initializing an array? because the original data may have variables which are named differently. such as Name, Age, PolicyName etc. so i need an alternative to array there.

Comment: Why? An array will still work fine, so let say you Name, Age, PolicyName, then you simply initialise like this: `var_array[*] Name Age PolicyName;` etc. Alternatively, you could build a logic based on a bunch of if statements in datastep or case login in proc sql to cycle through a list of variables until a non missing value.

Answer (score 0):

```
title;
data exp;
   infile cards dsd firstobs=2;
   input Policy_Number (var1-var3) ($) Exposure;
   arbitraryname243 = rank(first(var1));
   arbitraryname4 = rantbl(123,.4);
   arbitraryname36 = rank(first(var3));
   cards;
Policy_Number,var1,var2,var3,Exposure
1,B,H,J,191
2,B,F,Unknown,174
3,C,Unknown,I,153
4,B,G,L,192
5,Unknown,E,Unknown,184
6,D,E,K,113
7,C,Unknown,I,140
8,A,H,I,133
9,C,F,I,194
10,Unknown,G,Unknown,105
11,B,H,L,172
12,A,Unknown,I,198
13,D,E,K,155
14,Unknown,G,K,177
15,B,H,Unknown,100
16,D,Unknown,J,176
17,B,E,I,112
18,Unknown,E,J,192
19,C,Unknown,K,146
20,C,G,Unknown,187
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc transpose data=exp(obs=0 drop=policy_number exposure) out=varlist;
   var _all_;
   run;
Proc sql noprint; 
   select nliteral(_name_) into :classvars separated by ' ' from varlist;
   quit;
%put NOTE: &=classvars;
ods select none;
proc freq data=exp;
   tables &classvars / nocum;
   weight exposure;
   ods output onewayfreqs=freqs;
   run;
ods select all;

data freqs(keep=Variable Levels Frequency Percent);
   length Variable $32 Levels $64;
   set freqs;
   variable = substr(table,6);
   levels = coalesceC(of F_:);
   drop f_:;
   drop &classvars;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you explain me what SQL procedure is exactly doing here?

Comment: It is used to create the macro variable CLASSVARS from the data set of variable names, separated by spaces.  The list of variable names is created by PROC TRANSPOSE (OBS=0) of all names in EXP other than the two that are droped DROP=policy_number exposure.  This is the list of names you didn't want to type so I created it using programming.  This is a useful programming technique for a SAS user.